# Startup: Frequent "BundleException: State change in progress"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to listen to perspective state changes in my plugin, which I am doing in IStartup

```
public void earlyStartup() {
  Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     // register perspective listener to workbench
  }
 });
```

}

Launching IDE in a new workspace, after plugin update, I see below exception so frequently.

```
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.test.Startup", thread "Thread[Worker-2,5,main]" timed out waiting (5008ms) for thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "test.startup [55]". 
To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-2,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.test.Startup" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does your plugin Activator `start` method do anything?

Comment: Yes, it does some task. But none of them are time consuming.

Comment: Is it suggested to add perspective listener in BundleListener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am using my 'BundleListener' to register listeners like 'IWindowCloseHandler' and 'IPerspectiveListener' etc, after bundle is started.

```
public class StudioBundleListener implements BundleListener {
@Override
   public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent event) {
   String symbolicName = event.getBundle().getSymbolicName();
   int type = event.getType();
   if(symbolicName.equals(MYPlugin.PLUGIN_ID) && type == BundleEvent.STARTED) {
     //Register my listeners
   }
 }
}
```

This solved the class load issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it's better to call with in your Perspective factory Plugin Activator class start() method. That will avoid the errors which you are facing.

Invoke this at the end of start() method. This won't impact the performance of the plugin loading.

```
Job job = new UIJob("Add Perspective listener") {
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        addPerspectiveListener();
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
job.setSystem(true);
job.schedule();
```

Comment: Hi Kondal, Thanks for your suggestion! Could you please explain when will this exactly come into play in plugin load sequence ?

Comment: This will make you understand - http://exploreeclipse.blogspot.sg/search?q=State+change+in+progress+for+bundle+

Comment: I have added the UIJob at end of start() but I doubt the job is running! The breakpoint put at start of runInUIThread() is never hit!! Also checked by putting print statements, Job is scheduled but never running. Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Not possible!. I believe the plugin itself is not getting invoked. Put a debug point in the start() and see whether it's getting invoked or not.

Comment: start(context){
....
Job job = new UIJob("Add Perspective listener") {
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        logInfo("JOB running");
        addPerspectiveListener();
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
job.setSystem(true);
logInfo("JOB scheduled");
job.schedule();
}
 plugin got invoked and also 'JOB scheduled' got printed in logs, but could not find 'JOB running' in logs, even after my plugin started running!!